# How to reduce an array and add a count as a new field?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, however i need the array to add a count onto each object, and also remove any duplicates. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

CURRENT

```
[
 { id: 2, name: 'Adventure' },
 { id: 6, name: 'Crime' },
 { id: 2, name: 'Adventure' },
 { id: 3, name: 'Beautiful' },
 { id: 7, name: 'Drama' },
 { id: 2, name: 'Adventure' }
]
```

EXPECTED

```
    [
     { id: 2, name: 'Adventure', count: 3 },
     { id: 6, name: 'Crime', count: 1 },
     { id: 3, name: 'Beautiful', count: 1 },
     { id: 7, name: 'Drama', count: 1 }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let current = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Adventure' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Crime' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Adventure' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Beautiful' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Drama' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Adventure' }
]

let expected = current.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let curFind = acc.find(item => item.id === cur.id)
  if (curFind) {
    curFind.count++
    return acc
  } else {
    return [...acc, {
      ...cur,
      count: 1
    }]
  }
}, [])

console.log('expected:', expected)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well Iv. Good to also see how to do it with a single function.